# Where can I find the documentation for MicroStrategy Command Manager

Tags: microstrategy

Where can I find the documentation for MicroStrategy Command Manager?  I've look through various docs that I have but not able to find any comprehensive list of commands.  Particularly, I need to know a list of commands to create attributes and metrics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find the list of available commands is to use the Outlines option, available inside Command Manager.

To create an attribute use the following syntax:

```
CREATE ATTRIBUTE "<attribute_name>" [DESCRIPTION "<description>"] [LONGDESCRIPTION "<long_description>"] IN [FOLDER] "<location_path>" [HIDDEN (TRUE | FALSE)] ATTRIBUTEFORM "<form_name>" [FORMCATEGORY "<category_name>"] [FORMDESC "<form_description>"] [FORMTYPE (NUMBER | TEXT | DATETIME | DATE | TIME | URL | EMAIL | HTML | PICTURE | BIGDECIMAL | PHONENUMBER)] [REPORTSORT (NONE | ASC | DESC)] [BROWSESORT (NONE | ASC | DESC)] EXPRESSION "<form_expression>" [MAPPINGMODE (AUTOMATIC | MANUAL)] [EXPSOURCETABLES "<sourcetable1>" [, "<sourcetable2>" ...]] LOOKUPTABLE "<lookup_table>" FOR PROJECT "<project_name>";
```

and for metrics creation:

```
CREATE METRIC "<metric_name>" IN [FOLDER] "<location_path>" EXPRESSION "<expression>" [DESCRIPTION "<description>"] [LONGDESCRIPTION "<long_description>"] [HIDDEN (TRUE | FALSE)] [ALLOWSMARTMETRIC (TRUE | FALSE)] [REMOVEREPORTFILTERELEMENTS (TRUE | FALSE)] [TOTALSUBTOTALFUNCTION (AVERAGE | COUNT | DEFAULT| GEOMETRICMEAN | MAXIMUM | MEDIAN | MINIMUM | MODE | NONE | PRODUCT | STANDARDDEVIATION | SUM | VARIANCE)] [DYNAMICAGGREGATIONFUNCTION (AVERAGE | COUNT | DEFAULT| GEOMETRICMEAN | MAXIMUM | MEDIAN | MINIMUM | MODE | NONE | PRODUCT | STANDARDDEVIATION | SUM | VARIANCE)] [COLUMNALIAS "<columnalias>"] FOR PROJECT "<project_name>";
```

Some simple examples provided bellow (again from the outlines available inside command manager):

```
CREATE ATTRIBUTE "Day" DESCRIPTION "Duplicate of Day Attribute from folder \Time" IN FOLDER "\Schema Objects\Attributes" ATTRIBUTEFORM "ID" FORMCATEGORY "ID" FORMDESC "Basic ID form" FORMTYPE TEXT REPORTSORT ASC EXPRESSION "[DAY_DATE]" LOOKUPTABLE "LU_DAY" FOR PROJECT "MicroStrategy Tutorial";
CREATE METRIC "New Metric" IN FOLDER "\Public Objects\Metrics\Count Metrics" EXPRESSION "Count(Customer) {Country} <[Western United States Customers]>" FOR PROJECT "MicroStrategy Tutorial";
```

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno said, the Outlines option gives you all the templates that there are in Command Manager, which you can build together and define to do what you want. If in doubt, check out the "MicroStrategy System Administration Guide" product manual, which covers all you need to know on command manager.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one useful site with Command Manager documentation:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Business::Intelligence::MicroStrategy::CommandManager